# Connecting CSS in Django project

Tags: python, css, django

Please tell me what the error is. After running the  `python manage.py collectstatic` files were generated, the js scripts work, but the CSS file is not connected.

`base.html`

```
<!doctype html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   ....
    <!--Custome CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'static/css/style.css' %}">
    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
```

Folder:

[image: folder]

`settings.py`

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / STATIC_URL
```

I tried adding the code from the documentation:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Take a look at the resulting URL of the href attribute in the generated HTML document. Does it look the way you expect it to? I have the feeling that there may be one "static" folder too much.

Comment: @Matthias, I moved the file to the static folder and wrote: 'static/style.css’. Did not help

Comment: OK, you told us about the path in the template. But the question is: When the page is rendered in the browser and you look at the HTML source code, what path to the css file do you see?

Comment: It's pretty obvious the problem. Look at my answer.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I tried to write as indicated in the comments, but the problem was not solved. In the browser source code (in <head>):
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">

Comment: In project - <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

if your css file is into the static folder then you have to write like this,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
```

and when in static folder there is another folder like `css` folder so, at that time you have to write like this,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. The path was indeed wrong, but still needed to be removed:

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / STATIC_URL
```

What happened in the settings:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static"
]

#STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / STATIC_URL
```